# Equal height div containers

Tags: html, css, layout

I´m trying to create a 2 columns layout
- the whole page is on a placed within a div container with a width of 80%. 
- Within this container, I´m trying to create 2 columns, 
    First 20% width and second 80% width out of these 80% page width in total.
- the 2 columns are different in height

I´m struggling with 2 things:
- keep the wrapper background from the top to the bottom while not having 1 column floating next to other and eventually taking full page width (80% of it).

The solution, which led me to the correct page layout, but does not retain the background color (but also creates a hideous space between the h1 and nav) is following:

```css
body {
  background-color:rgb(77,77,77);
  background-image:url("images.jpg");
  background-attachment:fixed;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: rgba(253,251,220,0.9);
  width: 80%;
  min-height:100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position:relative;
}

.container {
  margin: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.aside_box {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  min-height:100%;
}

.box {
  background-color: rgba(253,251,220,0.9);
  border: 0 10em;
}

.box-70-100 {
  float: right;
  width: 80%;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgba(237, 164, 37, 0.8);
  overflow: hidden;
  float:top;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <header id="head">
      <h1>..</h1>
      <div class ="nav"></div>
    </header>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <article>
      <section>
        <div class="aside_box">
          <aside>
            <div class = "box">
              <h2>FQA</h2> 
            </div>
          </aside>   
        </div>
      </section>

      <section>
        <div class="box-70-100">
          <div class = "box"></div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: flex`. I added two new classes `flex-1` and `flex-2` instead of giving width use `flex: 5` or `flex-shrink: 5` or you can use `flex-basis: 80%` means that div will be 5 times bigger than `flex-1`.

you can read more about flex [here at css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Check this code:

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(77, 77, 77);
  background-image: url("images.jpg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: rgba(253, 251, 220, 0.9);
  padding: 0;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: stretch;
  align-content: stretch;
}

.flex-1 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  flex: 1;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}

.flex-2 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex: 5;
}

.container {
  min-height: 100%;
}

.aside_box {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.box {
  background-color: rgba(253, 251, 220, 0.9);
  border: 0 10em;
}

.box-70-100 {
  float: right;
  width: 80%;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgba(237, 164, 37, 0.8);
  overflow: hidden;
  float: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container flex-1">
    <header id="head">
      <h1>..</h1>
      <div class="nav"></div>
    </header>
  </div>
  <div class="container flex-2">
    <article>
      <section>
        <div class="aside_box">
          <aside>
            <div class="box">
              <h2>FQA </h2>
            </div>
          </aside>
        </div>
      </section>

      <section>
        <div class="box-70-100">
          <div class="box"></div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```